# Retrieve products in prestashop module and place module after check out page

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I am writing a module, let's call it **base**, which will show a button after vistor has clicked on buy+confirmed. That is the page where total price is displayed, a thank you message and an email will be send.

On that page, I would like to add my module with the button, which on-click sends product details to another web service. Now I have several questions:

1. Which hook can I use to place that button on the confirm (after checkout) page. As you can see I am using several hooks just to see if the button appears. It only appears in the leftCollumn
2. What do you think in general of the code. Would getProducts() be the right method, just copied from another standard module. Do you have an example for me?

*please ignore global. I will refactor later.*

**base.php** (only important part of it)

```
<?php
if ( !defined( '_PS_VERSION_' ) )
  exit;

class Base extends Module
{

  public function install() {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('payment') && $this->registerHook('invoice') && $this->registerHook('leftColumn');
  }

  public function uninstall() {
        parent::uninstall();
  }

  public function getContent() {
        return '<h2>'.$this->displayName.'</h2> <div>nothing to configure</div>';
  }

  public function hookPayment($params) {
        if (!$this->active)
          return;

        global $smarty;
        $smarty->assign('buttonText', $this->l('Send to my base'));
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'base.tpl');
}


  public function ajaxCall($params) {
        if (Configuration::get('PS_CATALOG_MODE'))
          return "return;";

        return $params['cart']->getProducts(true);
  }
}
```

**products.php**

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../init.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/base.php');

$cart = new Cart((int)($cookie->id_cart));
$cart->id_lang = (int)($cookie->id_lang);

$base = new Base();
var_dump( $base->hookAjaxCall(array('cookie' => $cookie, 'cart' => $cart)) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this hooks :

```
{$HOOK_ORDER_CONFIRMATION}
{$HOOK_PAYMENT_RETURN}
```

This hooks are displayed in order-confimation.tpl after payment validation.

Comment: hookPaymentReturn is what I wanted. Thanks for that. Can you also help me with the other issue? How do I get the products of the placed order and some details about the user? As expected, the cart is emtpy after order.

Comment: Ok, got my Answer. $params includes all the information I need. And a brief look in Classes of Prestashop helps to find out how to handle that data.